# KCachegrind output

Tags: c, linux, performance, valgrind, kcachegrind

I don't understand why my Kcachegrind's output is in this form
[image]

I'm compiling with

```
$valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=outputfile ./main.c
$kcachegrind outputfile
```

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the exact issue? Otherwise the correct answer will be "because your output is not in another form". Help yourself and other that will stumble upon this question by being specific.

Comment: Probably you forgot to add debugging flag "-g" during compilation.

Comment: I should see the function's names

Comment: @gudok How do I add it to Clion?

Comment: Can you build and run a small exe in a terminal to check that Valgrind is working correctly?